# Reference request : Convergence of radial basis function interpolation or spline interpolation as points become dense, for a continuous function

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, interpolation, splines

Is there any proof for this. Kindly request a reference in case available or any related documents towards this.

PS : I am specifically interested in the case of scattered data (irregularly placed), although any reference on the case of data placed on a uniform grid would also be valuable.